# Sitecore.Forms.MVC.dll 8.0 to 8.1 removed classes : FieldModel & SectionModel

Tags: forms, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc, web-forms-for-marketers

I am in the process of converting the deprecated methods & classes of WFFM from 8.0 rev.150429 (Update-3) to 8.1 rev. 151008 (Initial release). Sitecore provided a good documentation > release notes for the '**breaking changes**' that would occur when converted to WFFM 8.1.

Link to release note: 
https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Web%20Forms%20For%20Marketers/Web%20Forms%20For%20Marketers%2081/Web%20Forms%20For%20Marketers%2081%20Initial%20Version/Release%20Notes

And that includes moving some classes from *Sitecore.Form.Core.dll* to *Sitecore.WFFM.Abstractions.Actions.dll* (okay I understand).

**However,** though I am not really sure, maybe I just couldn't locate the right page/site, but there were also some changes made in the Sitecore.Forms.MVC 8.0 to 8.1 which were not documented. To be specific, classes are as follows:

1. `Sitecore.Forms.MVC.Models.FieldModel` (removed in Sitecore.Forms.MVC 8.1)
2. `Sitecore.Forms.MVC.Models.SectionModel` (removed in Sitecore.Forms.MVC 8.1)

Maybe there were also other classes that were removed, as well. But I am only concerned about the above two (2) classes for the mean time.

So, I'd like to know if someone already ran into this scenario before when upgrading WFFM to 8.1 and how you were able to resolved the issue?

I have a hint that I just have to look for the **NEW** DLL that uses or implements the `FieldModel` and `SectionModel`, but again, I couldn't find it as of this writing.

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no FieldModel and SectionModel anymore, but I assume you are looking for the FieldViewModel and SectionViewModel. They can be found still in Sitecore.Forms.Mvc in the Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.ViewModels namespace.

If you need more specific classes, you can check the Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.ViewModels.Fields as well - or open the Sitecore.Forms.Mvc dll with a decompiler (as I did).

Comment: Yes. I saw it already. Thank you. In addition to that, there were also other changes made inside these method like if you wanted to call FieldModel, the new implementation is to use the Type Parameter <T>.